# How to save this json array to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, string

I want to save this json array that my fb-login returns to a database. However I don't really know how to convert that into a string using php.

```
[{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}]
```

I have tried this code below but I am even not quite sure anymore whether what the fb login return is a json array or not.

```
$json = '{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

How would I be able to save the different sports to my database in a string?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: The upper part returns NULL.

---

SECOND EDIT:

```
if (array_key_exists('sports', $me)){


                    $json = '$me['sports']'; PROBLEM IS HERE
                    $data = json_decode($json, true);
                    $sports = array();
                    foreach ($data as $item) {
                        $sports[] = $item['name'];
                    }

                    $user->fb_sports = $sports;
                }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) or [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) should work just fine.

Comment: $json should have those square brackets around the outside - use http://jsoneditoronline.org/ to check if it is valid JSON.

Comment: And cross your fingers and hope you'll never have to query through this structured data saved as a string. Because who needs normal forms?

Comment: What is $me equal to? Also $json = '$me['sports']'; is not valid code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$json = '[{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}]';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$sports = array();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $sports[] = $item['name'];
}
```

if you want commas separating them:

```
$output = implode(', ', $sports);
```

Comment: this works fine. However, I get the error that what I receive from Facebook is an array, not a string. I have edited the question.

Comment: You need quotes before and after the square brackets like I've said in my answer. Otherwise it isn't valid PHP though it is valid Javascript. BTW what is $me equal to?

Comment: Can use use var_dump with $me and copy and paste the results?

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
 $json = serialize($json);
```

Comment: Now this is what is returned:

s:134:"{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}";

Is there a way to only save the sports?

Comment: $json = '[{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},   {"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}]';
$json = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($json as $value){
$sports[] = $value["name"];
}
$sports = serialize($sports);

Comment: I have edited the question. I get the error that what I receive from Facebook is an array, not a string.

Comment: the Facebook array containing user data from login.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json1 = '{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}';
$json2 = '[{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}]';

var_dump(json_decode($json1,true));
var_dump(json_decode($json2,true));
```

watch the difference

Answer (score 0):

If var_dump(json_decode($json)) returns what you'd expect just save $json directly into the database.

Comment: I would like to save a string of all the sports.

Comment: there should be square brackets around it all... try copying it into http://jsoneditoronline.org/ also use var_dump(json_decode($json, true)) to convert it into associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=mysql_real_escape_string($json);
```